# C++ multidimentional array with random numbers

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have a task and I have no any idea how to start. There should be array with dimensions 3x4 and I have to insert there generated random integers in range [-7,20). I have problem because I've never used multidimensional arrays. Please show me the simpliest solution.

Comment: I suggest starting with a simple "Hello World!" program and get it working.  Next, declare a two dimensional array, then fill it with known values and print them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best solution, on how to start, is to start with a foundation and add to it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

  std::cout << "Paused. Press ENTER to continue.\n";
  std::cin.ignore(1000000, '\n');
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The above short program will allow you to get your IDE and project set up correctly.  Get this working first.

Next, you may want to work with multidimensional arrays:

```
const unsigned int MAXIMUM_ROWS = 4;
const unsigned int MAXIMUM_COLUMNS = 3;

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Multidimensional array test\n\n";
  int my_array[MAXIMUM_ROWS][MAXIMUM_COLUMNS];
  for (size_t row = 0; row < MAXIMUM_ROWS; ++row)
  {
     for (size_t column = 0; column < MAXIMUM_COLUMNS; ++column)
     {
       my_array[row][column] = row * MAXIMUM_ROWS + column;
     }
  }
  // Now to print
  for (size_t row = 0; row < MAXIMUM_ROWS; ++row)
  {
     for (size_t column = 0; column < MAXIMUM_COLUMNS; ++column)
     {
       std::cout << my_array[row][column] << "\t";
     }
     std::cout << "\n";
  }

  std::cout << "Paused. Press ENTER to continue.\n";
  std::cin.ignore(1000000, '\n');
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Or, you could write a small program that generates random numbers within your range and prints them out.

Finally combine pieces of these working programs into your final masterpiece.

This is a technique of *how to start*.  Search the internet for "Test Driven Development" for additional techniques on starting a program or project.

Answer (score -1):

using a nested loop is the best idea.. with something like randr running in each loop